# PHPMailer codes won't send a message to an email in GoDaddy

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a project that needs to be done and our group life is on the line with this problem occurs to us. The problem is that it won't send a message to an email. In xampp localhost this phpmailer script works but after uploading to godaddy it happens to have some sort of problem. I tried various fix/solution with the forums I'd seen here in godaddy and still it won't work. For example like changing the host, port, smtp's auth and secure, and etc. Could somebody out there help me to find a fix for this even godaddy help support? I've been going at it for the past 2 weeks. Am I missing something? Do I have something to configure in cPanel? This is the script I made but it is just for a trial.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
try{
require ('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Username = 'msatwebsite@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '***************';
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@webmaster');
$mail->Subject ='MSU-MSAT Alumni Registration Confirmation';
$mail->Body = 'hello lagudas 3' ;
$mail->AddAddress('glysalagudas@gmail.com');
$mail->Send();
echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: what does using `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` return

Comment: i just comment it. so its not part of the code.

Comment: i tried that smtpdebug = 2 but it has no bugs :)

Comment: are you saying no output at all?

Comment: i'm saying that it won't send a message in email.

Comment: im referring to the debugging, adding `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` should give you some output

Comment: ow my bad haha this is the output after putting $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

 
2019-06-01 03:06:50 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2019-06-01 03:06:50 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: well theres the error

Comment: on this error can you figure out on how to fix or probably some solution you could give? or advice perhaps? I'm a little bit on the bind here :(

Comment: i have found out recently that if i comment $mail->isSMTP(); there is no error. but still it wont receive a message in email.

Comment: It’s because you’re using godaddy, who block outbound SMTP. Read the troubleshooting guide which describes this exact problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try using these lines of code in the beginning of your script if you haven't already, and make sure the directory is correct :-)

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no src folder in my PHPMailer folder. but there is class.smtp.php, class.phpmailer.php, PHPMailerAutoLoad.php, and etc.